# inject/pass value to a parameter in kube manifest file

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

This is a very simple thing I am trying to do. I have the below kube manifest file that creates a namespace.

`test-ns.yml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ${NAMESPACE}
```

all i am trying to do is `kubectl apply -f test-ns.yml --namespace=test`

This the error I am getting

`The Namespace "${NAMESPACE}" is invalid: metadata.name: Invalid value: "${NAMESPACE}": a DNS-1123 label must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'my-name',  or '123-abc', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?')`

I am not sure how to pass the NAMESPACE value to the kube manifest file. What am I doing wrong here? and how should I be doing this?

Comment: You should look to kustomize or helm

Comment: As Alex suggested You should try kustomize or helm. AFAIK this can't be done in k8s by default.